# Incompatible Mat in OpenCV for Android

Tags: android, opencv, mat

`prevPts = new MatOfPoint2f(prev);`

`prev` is a `Mat;`

The first line `prevPts = new MatOfPoint2f(prev);` raises and exception Incompatible MAT. I don't understand why it is doing this. The API says that MatOfPoint2f can take in a MAT.

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
MatOfPoint matOfPoint = ...code to receive ... 

MatOfPoint2f mat2f = new MatOfPoint2f();
matOfPoint.convertTo(mat2f, CvType.CV_32FC2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Constructor of new MatofPoint2f(MAT):

```
 public MatOfPoint2f(Mat m) {
        super(m, Range.all());
        if( !empty() && checkVector(_channels, _depth) < 0 )
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Incompatible Mat");
        //FIXME: do we need release() here?
    }
```

check your MAT object